# Common class/protocol for UIView/CALayer - software design issues

Tags: iphone, uiview, protocols, class-design, calayer

I have a very simple question regarding some software design decisions using the iOS SDK.

Suppose I have a class that manages the presentation of view objects in my application (`UIManager`). This class allows external controller classes to add view objects to it. The view objects can be of two kinds: `CALayer` and `UIView` subclasses.

My question is which interface is more well suited for such `UIManager` class.
For instance:

```
@interface UIManager : UIView {}

// 1)
- (void)addGenericViewObject:(id)genericViewObject;

// 2)
- (void)addUIViewObject:(UIView*)uiViewObject;
- (void)addCALayerObject:(CALayer*)caLayerObject;

// 3)
- (void)addMyProtocolTypeViewObject(id<MyProtocolType>)myProtocolTypeViewObject;
@end
```

1) The `id` type is too generic?

2) Having a different method signature for each type can lead to awful code duplication?

3) Is there a way to represent both `UIView` and `CALayer` class through `<MyProtocolType>` ?

Or more generally speaking, having class that handle these different objects interchangeable is not good?

The implementation of `UIManager` would be something like this:

```
@implementation UIManager

// 1)
- (void)addGenericViewObject:(id)genericViewObject {
    if ([genericViewObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        [_uiViewsContainer addSubview:(UIView*)genericViewObject];
    } else if ([genericViewObject isKindOfClass:[CALayer class]]) {
        [_caLayersContainer addSublayer:(CALayer*)genericViewObject];
    }
}
@end
```

Type checking is always bad, maybe having `<MyProtocolType>` would solve the situation, however, how could I represent both `UIView` and `CALayer` class in a protocol? Both classes just conform to `<NSObject>`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type checking is just so necessary.  I think that it is possible to reframe the question to…  “I want a manager to take either an UIView or a CALayer and do different things to them, but reject all the other things.”  In that case, type checking trumps hackery and I wholeheartedly recommend that you just type-check, and throw an exception when things do not go as expected.

It is possible to add a private category that is really, really private, like one with a 64-character random identifier, to both CALayer and UIView, which conforms the classes to a custom protocol, and just check for conformity.  But that does what type-checking does, and is an awful lot of (unnecessary) work; last time I tried, GCC appears to hate that.

I think this could work, if later on you are dealing with lots of classes:

```
- (BOOL) addInterfaceObject:(id)anObject {

    void (^handler)();

    if (!(handler = [self interfaceObjectHandlerForClass:[anObject class]]))
    return NO;  // Or throw an exception

    handler(anObject);
    return YES;

}

- (void(^)(id anObject)) interfaceObjectHandlerForClass:(Class)aClass {

//  Or retrieve copy-autoreleased blocks from a dictionary

    if ([aClass isSubclassOfClass:[UIView class]])
    return ^ (id anObject) { [self.view addSubview:(UIView *)anObject]; };

    if ([aClass isSubclassOfClass:[CALayer class]])
    return ^ (id anObject) { [self.view.layer addSublayer:(CALayer *)anObject]; };

    return nil;

}
```

Comment: So, the solution for the `UIManager` class interface is the 1), which means that `addGenericViewObject:` argument should unavoidable be generalized to `id`. The use of blocks/exceptions inside the `UIManager` class looks like a good way to handle the `id` generality. The solution 2) is definitely the worst. The solution 3) is what I was looking for: a protocol that represents both UIView and CALayer and allows the `UIManager` class to define a specific contract for the method arguments through such protocol instead of `id`.

Comment: I think that a protocol could work, but am personally against that. ;)

Comment: By copying and pasting your code snippet into my `UIManager` class (a UIView subclass) I got the following error: "Returning block that lives on the local stack" in the following lines: `return ^ (id anObject) { [self addSubview:(UIView *)anObject]; };` and `return ^ (id anObject) { [self.layer addSublayer:(CALayer *)anObject]; };`. Looks Like I can't access `self` properly from that point what's wrong?

Comment: Oh, certainly an oversight.  Please return [[^ {} copy] autorelease] so it goes from the stack to the heap (?) and can be used outside the stack.